# select() and poll() in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, file-descriptor

So, I have been reading about select and poll man pages, but unfortunately, I am still confused about some things. It would nice if someone can answer the following questions for me:

- What happens when a file in opened in non-blocking mode? (O_NONBLOCK flag is set)
- When there is data is the buffer, read() blocks or returns what?
- And what happens when there isn't any data in the buffer to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens when a file in opened in non-blocking mode? (O_NONBLOCK
>   flag is set)

- If the file can't be opened immediately, open() returns an error instead of blocking, open() may block only with FIFOs.
- If the open() is successful, all IO operations will be non-blocking. It means, if the IO operations can't be completed immediately, it would be performed partially or it fails with an error (EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK).

> When there is data is the buffer, read() blocks or returns what?

- The difference between blocking and non-blocking read() occurs when there is no data to read. Therefore, when there is data in the buffer, non-blocking read() returns it.

> And what happens when there isn't any data in the buffer to read?

- If there is no data, non-blocking read() returns with EAGAIN error.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens when a file in opened in non-blocking mode? (O_NONBLOCK flag is set)

I/O operations don't block and instead return an error code that indicates they would have blocked.

> When there is data is the buffer, read() blocks or returns what?

When there is data in the buffer, `read` returns it.

> And what happens when there isn't any data in the buffer to read?

If the socket is blocking, it blocks until some data can be returned. If the socket is non-blocking, it returns an error code that indicates that it would have blocked had the socket been blocking.

By the way, one important caution with `select` and `poll` -- they should almost never be used with blocking sockets. When you get a read or write hit from `select` or `poll`, that means a hypothetical, canonical operation performed at some time in-between when you called the function and when it returned would not have blocked. These are status-reporting functions and do not provide future guarantees. If you are writing a program that must never block, it must set all its sockets non-blocking.